# How to stop line breaking in vim

Tags: vim

I like that the long lines are displayed over more than one terminal line;  I don’t like that vim inserts newlines into my actual text. Which part of .vimrc I should change?

Comment: For clarity:  you like that the long lines are displayed over more than one terminal line; you don't like that vim inserts newlines into your actual text?  If so, then `:set nowrap` is the opposite of what you want :(.

Comment: @Andrew : yes your summary is exact what I want

Comment: **Line breaks appearing when typing in `.txt` file?**

If you're using the example `.vimrc`, it sets `textwidth` for plaintext files. Thought I'd mention that in case anyone was having the same issue as me.

Answer (score 342):

Use

```
:set wrap
```

To wrap lines visually, i.e. the line is still one line of text, but Vim displays it on multiple lines.

Use

```
:set nowrap
```

To display long lines as just one line (i.e. you have to scroll horizontally to see the entire line).

Comment: Thanks for the tips you guys.  I went with :set nowrap and :set textwidth=0 works great

Comment: When I type I still want to see "visual" 80 column limit and i dont want vim to auto add line feed when I type after the 80th colomn. How do I do?

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for, but it's not the answer to OP's question. It's a bit misleading to have this as the top answer. I don't know how to fix this situation. I would just edit your answer to also answer the original question. But there is already a proper answer that is almost as highly voted. So I just voted to switch the two answers.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was *not* looking for, and it's *not* the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 223):

> I like that the long lines are displayed over more than one terminal line

This sort of visual/virtual line wrapping is enabled with the `wrap` window option:

```
:set wrap
```

By default this will wrap at the first character that won't fit in the window. This means it will wrap in the middle of a word if that's where the window boundary lies. To change it to wrap on word boundaries, you can also:

```
:set linebreak
```

This will cause `wrap` to only wrap at the characters in the `breakat` setting, which defaults to space, tab, and small set of punctuation characters.

```
:set breatat
  breakat= ^I!@*-+;:,./?
```

> I don’t like that vim inserts newlines into my actual text.

To turn off physical line wrapping, clear both the `textwidth` and `wrapmargin` buffer options:

```
:set textwidth=0 wrapmargin=0
```

Comment: Thanks! `set textwidth=0 wrapmargin=0` works but if I put it into `.vimrc`, it doesn't have an effect for example for plain text files. How do I find out and eliminate the overwrite?

Comment: @qubodup You can test if something is overwriting your .vimrc setting by opening a file where you see the problem and entering `:verbose set textwidth? wrapmargin?`. This will tell you their current values and also where they were set. It's possible that you have a plugin that's overriding them. In that case you may either uninstall that plugin, or try overriding the plugin setting later in your runtimepath (eg:`~/.vim/after`) or with your own autocommand. The right approach will depend on where/how it's being reset.

Comment: `set wrap` and `set linebreak` is what did it for me.

Comment: 1. Probably `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/foo.vim` will override `~/.vim/plugin/**/foo.vim`, so `:verbose ...` said by Gonsalves is really helpful for knowing the problems (also see `:h runtimepath` and `:h initialization`). Then we need to modify `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/foo.vim` (`~/.vim/plugin/**/foo.vim` may not override the related files in `ftplugin`). 2. As the doc says, `set wrap` and `set linebreak` are for *displaying* but not for *editing*.

Answer (score 47):

Try removing the `t` option from `formatoptions`:

```
:set formatoptions-=t
```

The `t` option will insert line breaks to make text wrap at the width set by `textwidth`. You can also put this command in your `.vimrc`, just remove the colon (`:`).

Comment: This seems to me the best option for addressing the OP's wish. I like the fact that vim still shows a vertical line at `tw`.

Comment: This is the only answer actually addressing OP's question. Most others do the opposite. OP still wants long lines to be displayed wrapped around, but for vim not to insert line breaks automatically.

Comment: 12 years later and still not the most upvoted answer :s

Answer (score 41):

`:set tw=0`

VIM won't auto-insert line breaks, but will keep line wrapping.

Comment: I want exactly the opposite... it when I type I still want to see "visual" 80 column limit and i dont want vim to auto add line feed when I type after the 80th colomn. How do I do?

Comment: Exactly what I needed! This is required if you normally have `tw` set, and want to disable it.

Answer (score 37):

Use `:set nowrap` .. works like a charm!

Comment: Except that it does the opposite of what the OP defines as wanted behaviour... :P

Comment: @Morlock , but answers the question I had and google led me here :)

Comment: is there any keyboard shortcut for this ?

Comment: @PiniCheyni , add to your .vimrc file:
nnoremap <C-w> :set invwrap<CR>
Then you can use Ctrl+W to toggle text wrapping.

Answer (score 16):

You may find `set linebreak` useful; with `set wrap` on this will wrap but only cutting the line on whitespace and not in the middle of a word.

e.g.

```
without linebreak the li
ne can be split on
a word
```

and

```
with linebreak on the
line will be
split on 
whitespace only
```

Comment: It is highlly recommended to avoid abbreviating options because in the future you will have to make a search on the help system to understand what you have settled, so use `set nolinebreak` instead of `set lbr`

Answer (score 14):

`set formatoptions-=t` Keeps the visual textwidth but doesn't add new line in insert mode.

Answer (score 5):

Its strange that such a simple setting would require this amount of 'hocus-pocus' to work.

To answer your question now, for me it seemed to work with the combination of the following:

```
:set wrap linebreak nolist
```

(this seems to prevent existing lines from breaking, just wrap.)

AND

```
set formatoptions=l
```

(this prevents new/edited lines from breaking, while += does not do it for me as other settings/plugins seem to find space and add their own options which override mine.)

Answer (score 4):

If, like me, you're running gVim on Windows then your *.vimrc* file may be sourcing another 'example' Vimscript file that automatically sets `textwidth` (in my case to `78`) for text files.

[My answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7736/2629) to a similar question as this one – [How to stop gVim wrapping text at column 80](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2784/how-to-stop-gvim-wrapping-text-at-column-80) – on [the Vi and Vim Stack Exchange site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/):

> In my case, [Vitor's comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2784/how-to-stop-gvim-wrapping-text-at-column-80/2786#comment2888_2784) suggested I run the following:
>
> ```
> :verbose set tw?
> ```
>
> Doing so gave me the following output:
>
> ```
> textwidth=78
>       Last set from C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vimrc_example.vim
> ```
>
> In *vimrc_example.vim*, I found the relevant lines:
>
> ```
> " Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
> if has("autocmd")
>
>   ...
>
>   " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
>   autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78
>
>   ...
> ```
>
> And I found that my *.vimrc* is sourcing that file:
>
> ```
> source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
> ```
>
> In my case, I don't want `textwidth` to be set for any files, so I just commented out the relevant line in *vimrc_example.vim*.

Comment: Rather than editing the vimrc_example.vim file, I just added `autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=0` to the vimrc file and that fixed the problem when other proposed solutions did not.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct that *set nowrap* will allow you to paste in a long line without vi/vim adding newlines, but then the line is not visually wrapped for easy reading. It is instead just one long line that you have to scroll through.

To have the line visually wrap but not have newline characters inserted into it, have *set wrap* (which is probably default so not needed to set) and *set textwidth=0*.

On some systems the setting of **textwidth=0** is default. If you don't find that to be the case, add *set textwidth=0* to your .exrc file so that it becomes your user's default for all vi/vim sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I personnally went for:

- `set wrap`,
- `set linebreak`
- `set breakindent`
- `set showbreak=ͱ`.

Some explanation:

- `wrap` option visually wraps line instead of having to scroll horizontally
- `linebreak` is for wrapping long lines at a specific character instead of just anywhere when the line happens to be too long, like in the middle of a word. By default, it breaks on whitespace (word separator), but you can configure it with `breakat`. It also does NOT insert `EOL` in the file as the OP wanted.
- `breakat` is the character where it will visually break the line. No need to modify it if you want to break at whitespace between two words.
- `breakindent` enables to visually indent the line when it breaks.
- `showbreak` enables to set the character which indicates this break.

See `:h <keyword>` within vim for more info.

Note that you don't need to modify `textwidth` nor `wrapmargin` if you go this route.