# How to stop vim from putting text onto a new line after 80 characters?

Tags: unix, vim

Right now if I have a line like below and I try to add a character like an apostrophe:

```
 82 INSERT INTO Materials ( "Accession_Symbol", "Accession_Number", "Media") Values( Wil,   2314,   'oil');
```

Vim will automatically break my text into two lines like below

```
 82 INSERT INTO Materials ( "Accession_Symbol", "Accession_Number", "Media") 
 83 Values( 'Wil,   2314,   'oil');
```

From what I've read online it sounds like this happens after 80 columns or characters. I want to know how to stop this.

Comment: you are looking for wrap see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280030/how-to-stop-line-breaking-in-vim

Comment: No I don't think I am, unless wordwrap is something different than :set wrap which I could not see on that link you posted. :set wrap will change my view so that lines that reach the end of the screen will wrap around, in this case the line would still be line 82. My vim is actually putting the text onto a new line. From my second example you can see the text is put onto line 83 @Doon

Comment: How did you enter the character? Did you use `i'<ESC>` while the cusor was standing on W? For what we can tell, your cursor was on the V, end you entered `i<enter><right><right><right><right><right><right><right><right><right>'<ESC>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove breaking line with:

```
:set textwidth=0
```

Or change it to your desired width.