# Vim: auto linebreak works on C++ comments but not code

Tags: c++, vim, line-breaks

I'm cross-posting this question from [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12790/auto-linebreak-works-on-c-comments-but-not-code) after no eyes visited that question, and also reading that [it is acceptable to post Vim questions on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306014/vim-question-in-stackoverflow).

I use Vim for C and C++ coding. Following is my `.vimrc`:

```
execute pathogen#infect()

set backspace=indent,eol,start
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
set smarttab
set cino+=(0
set statusline=
set statusline +=\[%n]    " buffer number
set statusline +=\%F      " File
set statusline +=%=%l/%L  " currentLine/totalLine
set statusline +=%4v      " virtual column
set laststatus=2
set number
set nowrap
set ruler                 " show the cursor position all the time
set scrolloff=7           " start scrolling when cursor is 7 lines from top/bottom
set t_Co=256
set textwidth=80
set formatoptions=croqlt  " Hard-wrap when typing exceeds <textwidth>
set hlsearch
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType make set noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=0
colorscheme torte
```

I'm no expert vim scripter - the above is cobbled together from google searches for the various behaviors I desired.

I wanted auto linebreak at 80 chars so that text is intelligently wrapped at 80 chars (i.e. words are not chopped at the boundary, but a line of text is chopped at the nearest whitespace) - as I type. I was led to believe the `textwidth` and `formatoptions` fields above should do so, but the resulting behavior is that only comments are intelligently linebroken, *not code*. E.g. following is what Vim displayed as I typed:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  // Here's some C++-style comments. Happily, this line gets intelligently
  // line-broken as I type.

  int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, why_does_this_reach_this_far_without_linebreaking;

  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please advise what needs to be added to/corrected in my `.vimrc` to turn on intelligent linebreaking for code?

Comment: Remove `set nowrap` from .vimrc Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280030/how-to-stop-line-breaking-in-vim

Comment: @ManojBisht - Beautiful. Thank you. I have no idea why I had `set nowrap` in there in the first place. In retrospect, it should have been an obvious suspect. Please post as an answer if you'd like answer points.

Comment: `wrap`/`nowrap` just change the way long lines are displayed.  It doesn't actually insert line breaks in the buffer.  Is that what you want, or do you want the behavior you get with comments where an actual newline character is inserted?

Comment: @ManojBisht - After reading your posted link, I thought visual wrapping would be enabled. But no, `vim` actually works exactly as I desired after removing `set nowrap`: visual word-wrapping is disabled and line-breaking is enabled. I guess I'm still confused over visual wrapping versus linebreak-insertion. But regardless your suggestion solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @MilesBudnek - I thought exactly what you noted. I'm surprised then, that vim works as desired after ManojBisht's suggestion: visual wrapping is disabled and actual linebreak insertion is enabled. I'm curious why, but my immediate problem is solved.