# Wrap lengthy hyperlink in git commit

Tags: git, git-commit

When some hyperlink (or web page link) is included in the git commit message, I am able to click on the link and it is opening in the new browser tab.

I want to include a hyperlink in a git commit message. Hyperlink length is greater than 80 characters. I am able to wrap normal text to next line with `set textwidth=80`

I want to wrap that link to the next line in the message such that when I click on the link (or copy link option), the respective page should open in the browser.

Comment: `set textwidth=80` looks like a `vi` command. Do you use `vi` as your `GIT_EDITOR`?

Comment: Whether a link broken over two lines will still be clickable (and be complete) is not something you can solve in the editor, there's no magic markers or anything, it is only up to the viewing application whether it "understands" that the link is broken or not.

Comment: @Zeta, Yes. I use Vi

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, I am using `xfce4-terminal`. I think most of the terminals able to recognise the links. I am expecting for terminals only.

Comment: @NayabBashaSayed so you want to *view* the commit line-wrapped, not *write* it that way.

Comment: @Zeta, I need the link not to be broken, in any ways.

Comment: The way I understood the question is that OP wants to break the link when typing it into the commit message, in such a way that when later viewed, and then clicked on, the whole link is opened, not just the part on the line that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Check if one of the solution of "[How to stop line breaking in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2280030/6309)" could work in your case.

For instance, try in your `.vimrc` to add (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140828/6309))

```
:set wrap linebreak nolist
 set formatoptions=l
```

See then if you can copy-paste a long URL without having vim breaking it in multiple lines.